# Date validation in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a StartDate field and a EndDate field. Both may start today or in the future. It is possible to have them both start on the same day, including today.
I have to make a validation for these.
What I've done so far is this:

```
'StartDate'=>'required|date_format:Y/m/d|after:yesterday',
'EndDate'  => 'date_format:Y/m/d|after:yesterday',
```

What I don't know how to do is to validate true if both dates are equal as a second condition.

Anyone can help me, please ?

Comment: validation only apply when there is condition to something went wrong, but in your requirement, if its same date or from the future. But you can validate it should not the same or should be future date etc etc... if that not please describe what condition you want to apply validation on.

Comment: Where did you get the yesterday part?

Comment: @aldrin27 "yesterday" is a built-in functionality of laravel... in this case, if StartDate were before yesterday, it would return an error.

Comment: @Safoor Safdar: startdate and enddate may be today or any date in the future, enddate mai be equal or after start date. how can i build this in laravel ?

Comment: It seems that the problem is too complicated...

Comment: It seems that the problem is too complicated...  I searched on google and other people hit the same situation.... Maybe I should rephrase: what I need is a way to tell laravel  something like this: after OR equal:StartDate

Answer (score 29):

This is how you can validate date:

```
'start_date'  =>  'required|date',
'end_date'    =>  'required|date|after_or_equal:start_date'
```

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT**
This was a solution up to Laravel 5.3. With Laravel 5.4, a rule `after_or_equal` was introduced

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-after-or-equal

---

I had the same need for my web app. I solved it by creating a custom `Request` with the following `rules` method :

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
       'start_date'  => 'date_format:Y-m-d|after:today'
    ];

    if ($this->request->has('start_date') && $this->request->get('start_date') != $this->request->get('end_date')) {
       $rules['end_date'] = 'date_format:Y-m-d|after:start_date';
   } else {
       $rules['end_date'] = 'date_format:Y-m-d|after:today';
   }

   return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per my understand I try to prepare custom validation rule which could help you to meet your requirement.

Current below mentioned rule only check if a start date is before end date.

```
<?php 

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Validator;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

        public function boot(){
            Validator::extend('date_after', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
                return strtotime( $value ) > strtotime( $this->attributes[ $parameters[0] ] );
            });
            Validator::extend('date_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
                return strtotime( $value ) == strtotime( $this->attributes[ $parameters[0] ] );
            });
        }
    }

?>
```

#### Usage:

```
<?php 


$inputs = array(
  'start_date' => '2013-01-20',
  'end_date'   => '2013-01-15'
);

$rules = array(
  'start_date' => 'required',
  'end_date'   => 'required|date_after:start_date'
);

$messages = array(
  'date_after' => ":attribute must be date after Start Date."
);

$validation = Validator::make($inputs, $rules, $messages);

if( $validation->fails() )
{

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($validation->errors);
  echo '</pre>';

}

?>
```

However I did not test that code with my env... but I believe its help you much to meet requirement.

Please let me know your further requirement so I can provide specifically solution to your requirement.